# Performing multiple Linq queries against the same Linq result

Tags: c#, performance, linq

I have created a dashboard that all data displayed on it shares 4 common elements (startDate,endDate,CompanyID,StoreID) that are used as Where clauses in a Linq statement. The result of that statement is then queried in a variety of ways to group and sort the data and used in charts, lists etc. Here is a short snippit to show the duplication that is currently going on:

```
var dashboardEntity = new BlueStreakSalesDWEntities();

  //Get Total Sales
ViewBag.companySalesTotal = dashboardEntity.FactSales.Where(d => d.DateKey >= startDate)
                                                     .Where(d => d.DateKey <= endDate)
                                                     .Where(c => c.CompanyID == companyID)
                                                     .Sum(a => a.Amount);

//get list of all items sold
var companyStoreTotalItem = dashboardEntity.FactSales.Where(d => d.DateKey >= startDate)
                                           .Where(d => d.DateKey <= endDate)
                                           .Where(c => c.CompanyID == companyID).GroupBy(m => new { m.Description })
                                           .Select(g => new DescriptionAmountModel { Amount = g.Sum(a => a.Amount).Value, Description = g.Key.Description })
                                           .OrderByDescending(x => x.Amount);
```

I have like 15 of these calls on the dashboard and it can get very slow at times from what I imagine are multiple calls when in reality the database only needs to be queried once then that result needs to be queried for different results.

How can I do this?

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your current solution each query executes separatly, on the same data. You can first execute the shared parts of the queries and bring the results from database. In your examples it is these `where` conditions

```
//Executes in database
var entities = dashboardEntity.FactSales.Where(d => d.DateKey >= startDate)
                                        .Where(d => d.DateKey <= endDate)
                                        .Where(c => c.CompanyID == companyID)
                                        .ToList();
```

Now that this data is filtered to only what you want you can in memory do the rest of the aggregations:

```
//Happens in the List<T> in memory
ViewBag.companySalesTotal = entities.Sum(a => a.Amount);

var companyStoreTotalItem = entities.GroupBy(m => new { m.Description })
                                    .Select(g => new DescriptionAmountModel { Amount = g.Sum(a => a.Amount).Value, Description = g.Key.Description })
                                    .OrderByDescending(x => x.Amount);
```

Comment: Thanks this makes a lot more sense.

Comment: @NateGreene - you are welcome :)  you can also put all those `where` conditions in the same `Where` function with an `&&` operator. Will translate to the exact same sql but might look a bit cleaner

Comment: You cannot execute entity-framework tasks in parallel against a single context.  You don't gain anything from querying in memory entities using async/await tasks.

Answer (score 0):

This way you can make efficient. This make the query execute single time in database and rest of the part happen on the pullout in memory data

```
var result = dashboardEntity.FactSales.Where(d => d.DateKey >= startDate && d => d.DateKey <= endDate && d.CompanyID == companyID).ToList();

ViewBag.companySalesTotal = result.Sum(a => a.Amount); 

//then get list of all items sold from in memory data
var companyStoreTotalItem = result.GroupBy(m => new { m.Description }).Select(g => new DescriptionAmountModel { Amount = g.Sum(a => a.Amount).Value, Description = g.Key.Description }).OrderByDescending(x => x.Amount);
```